# UIViewController is not receiving touchesBegan message

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, touch

I have a UIScrollView in my UIViewController. I need to detect ANY kind of touch on it, and then do something. What else do I need?

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"TOUCHED"); // never happens
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if ( [touch view] == self.myScrollView)
        {
            //do something
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is the scroll view covering the whole view controller? If so, then it is first in the responder chain.

Comment: No, it's only in a portion of the view.

Comment: How do I get the scrollview to forward the touch events to the view controller?

Comment: Actually touches aren't detected anywhere on the view controller, even on the views that aren't scrollviews.

Comment: You do have touches enabled for it, right?

Answer (score 3):

Two choices:

1. Subclass UIScrollView and implement your touchesBegan[...] code
   there
2. Add a UIView to your UIScrollView and use the UIView's
       touchesBegan[...] delegate method

Answer (score -1):

use a controller to set the `UserInteractionEnabled` property to `true` on a `UIView` class.

try `imgTouchMe.UserInteractionEnabled = true;`

or follow

[image]